# Block communication between vehicles and RSU

Tags: omnet++, veins

Is there any way to block the communication between a certain vehicle and the RSU while the vehicle is in range that allows the communication between them?

I'm using Veins 5.1 and OMNeT++ 5.6.2 in Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to simulate (or what you are hoping your model will be able to do). I would appreciate a more elaborate description

Comment: I am hoping to somehow have a node (static) that will block the communication between the RSUs and the vehicle(s) that are near by. Something similar to a jammer, not with the physical approach, but more as a result to the V2X communication.

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing is a jammer: a node that creates interference for any node close by, hindering its ability to communicate. While no model of such a node is included in Veins 5.1, there are multiple ways to achieve this effect. Two ways I can think of are:

- Place an RSU that repeatedly sends 802.11p broadcasts on the wireless channel close to where you want to hinder communication. [Configure its Clear Channel Assessment (CCA) threshold](https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/veins-5.1/src/veins/modules/phy/PhyLayer80211p.ned#L40) to very high, so that it essentially always perceives the channel to be free. This could model a node using an 802.11p radio that is maliciously interfering with radio transmissions.
- Modify the [PHY layer of radios](https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/veins-5.1/src/veins/base/phyLayer/BasePhyLayer.h#L435) to allow you to either

  - support programmatically changing the amount of noise a node perceives (then change this noise floor for nodes as they move closer to - or further away from -  the jammer...
  - ...or to support returning values from `getNoiseFloorValue()` which depend on the geographic position of the node. Both ways could model a node that just emits (e.g., white gaussian) noise to jam nearby radio transmissions.